# Any other way to set window brightness?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I maintain an auto-brightness app which uses an overlay to set screen brightness. The brightness is set through `LayoutParams.screenBrightness`.

Up to lollipop, I used `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` for overlay type and everything was fine.

However, lollipop sees this overlay type as a threat or something and:

1. Doesn't turn on the screen automatically at all if such an overlay is present
2. If overlay is added later, the full screen notification such as alarm or incoming phone call will be suspended and reduced to notification bar

Naturally, this is a huge issue for me.

I have tested other window types and found that `TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE`, `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, `TYPE_TOAST` all work (in the sense that they don't cancel the full-screen notification), but they won't respect brightness commands while in lock screen.

Is there any other way I could set screen brightness while in lock screen?